# Removing spaces from string, adding words to array in C

Tags: c, arrays, regex, string

I am trying to remove all spaces from a string and add each word into a string array.

For instance, provided the string:

```
char command[120] = "apple   banana orange  dogfood"
```

an array, defined as:

```
char *items[20+1]; //Maximum 20 items in string + 0
```

would contain the elements:

```
{"apple", "banana", "orange" "dogfood"}
```

That is, all spaces have been removed.

My goal is to be able to make the call:

```
echo    1    3 2
```

and printing out

```
1 3 2
```

instead of

```
    1    3 2
```

**CODE**

So far, I have the following:

```
    char temp_array[120];
    //Populate array with words
    int i, j = 0, ant = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(command); i++) {
        if(isspace(command[i]) || command[i] == '\0') {
            if(ant <= 20) {
                temp_array[j] = '\0';
                memo = (char *) malloc(sizeof(temp_array)); //allocate memory
                strcpy(memo, temp_array);
                items[ant] = memo;
                memset(temp_array, 0, j);
                ant++;
                j= 0;
            }
        }
        else if(!isspace(command[i])) {
            temp_array[j] = command[i];
            j++;
        }
    }//Done populating array
    items[ant] = NULL;
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: `char *items[20+1]` is array of 21 string pointers. To define N elements of 20+1 chars, write `char items[][20+1]`.

Comment: @i486: The char array should be able to contain a maximum of 20 words (pluss 1), not a maximum of 20 characters.

Comment: Help with what problem?

Comment: Can you outline what part of your code does not seem to work? (I'm only assuming it doesn't.) Must you duplicate the strings, or is it enough to have *pointers* into `command`? This mainly depends on where `command` came from and what its lifetime is through your program.

Comment: There are library functions that will do this for you. Look up [`strtok()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html) and [`strsep()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strsep.3.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem may be solved naturally using `strtok`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str[] = "apple   banana orange  dogfood";
    char *items[20] = { NULL };
    char *pch;

    pch = strtok( str," \t\n" );
    int i = 0;
    while( NULL != pch )
    {
        items[i++] = pch;
        pch = strtok( NULL, " \t\n" );
    }

    for( i = 0; i < 20; i++ )
    {
        if( NULL != items[i] )
        {
            printf( "items[%d] = %s\n", i, items[i] );
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
items[0] = apple
items[1] = banana
items[2] = orange
items[3] = dogfood
```

Comment: **Note:** the pointers assigned to the `items` array are only valid so long as the memory containing `str` remains valid. You will need to provide *adequate storage* for, and *copy*, each string pointed to by `pch` to `items` (instead of simply assigning the pointer) if for instance you call `strtok` in a function and return a pointer to `items`.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through each character. If it's a space, continue. If it's not, add the address of that character to the array, loop until the first occurring space and replace it with a null terminator. Repeat.

Note that this destroys your initial string (`command` in your case). Also remember it must be modifiable (cannot be a read-only string).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that identify words in a string and stores them in an array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int GetWords(char *String,char **buffer);

int main(void)
{
    char command[120] = "   apple   banana orange  dogfood";

    char *items[20+1];

    int num_of_words = GetWords(command,items);

    for( int n = 0 ; n < num_of_words ; n++ )
    {
        printf("%s ",items[n]);
        free(items[n]);
    }
    puts("");
    return 0;
}

int GetWords(char *String,char **buffer)
{
    int x = -1 , y = 0 , z = 0 ;

    size_t len = strlen(String) , n ;

    for( n = 0 ; n < len ; n++ )
    {
        y++;

        if( String[n] == ' ' )
        {
            y = 0;
            z = 0;
        }

        if( y == 1 )
        {
            x++;
            buffer[x] = (char*)malloc(len+1);
        }

        if( y > 0 )
        {
            buffer[x][z] = String[n];
            z++;
            buffer[x][z] = '\0';
        }
    }
    //return number of words
    return (x+1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String Current = "hello java example";
String trimstr=Current.trim().replace(" ", "");

int count=trimstr.length();

String tryarray[]=new String[count];
for(int i =0;i<count;i++){
tryarray[i]=trimstr.substring(i, i+1);
System.out.println(trimstr.substring(i, i+1));
}
System.out.println("arrays is "+Arrays.toString(tryarray));
```

Comment: What is `String tryarray[]=new String[count];` in this C language post?